# How to Auto Reload the php file content using php?

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo, reload

I have database config file with pdo connection (config.php).This is the content of this file.

```
$db_host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "my_database_name";//@ This line is dynamically Adding
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";  
    // @Connecting the database with above credentials
    try{
        $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
        $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I am adding the `$db_name = "my_database_name";` line using some script. And then immediately I am using This database name for crud operation. But This config.php file showing

> Notice: Undefined variable: db_name in F:\xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\config\config.php on line 7

As per my knowledge the issue is because of adding the **$db_name** dynamically. So If we auto reload that **config.php** php file immediately then it will work. How to Auto reload the php file?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing - are you saying you're dynamically writing the $db_name = "my_database_name"; line to the config.php file?

Comment: yes, I am adding $db_name = "my_database_name"; dynamically.And using the same database name for crud operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the contents of a config file in a function (or even better a class to go OOP). Then you can call the function with the name database name whenever you want. By returning the connection you'll always have the right connection.

application.php

```
require_once('db.php');
$conn1 = getDBConnection('db1');
// do stuff on db1

$conn2 = getDBConnection('db2');
// do stuff on db2 (or db1 since its still open)
```

db.php

```
function getDBConnection($db_name) {
    // make the connection
    return $db_connection;
}
```